# Access control lists and permissions

Tags: files, permissions, security, users, acl

I am trying to complete the following task.
(I first created the /Homework directory as the root user)

> Create a directory named /Homework

```
mkdir /Homework
```

> Allow all users  to read this directory. But nothing else.

```
chmod 444 /Homework
```

> Create three folders inside /Homework
>
> Bob_homework

```
mkdir Bob_homework
```

> Tim_homework

```
mkdir Tim_homework
```

> Ben_homework

```
mkdir Ben_homework
```

> Give Bob (and only Bob) read and write access to /Homework/Bob_homework

```
chown Bon: Bob_homework     

setfacl -m u:Bob:rw/Homework/Bob_homework
```

> Give Tim (and only Tim) read and write access to /Homework/Tim_homework

```
chown Tim: Tim_homework     

setfacl -m u:Tim:rw /Homework/Tim_homework
```

> Give Ben (and only Ben) read and write access to /Homework/Ben_homework

```
chown Ben: Ben_homework

 setfacl -m u:Ben:rw /Homework/Ben_homework
```

After I did all of these, I still can't get Tim to access his directory.
Same goes for Bob & Ben.

Where did I go wrong ?
I also have another question.

Even though the permission for the Homework directory is set to 444.

The root user and read,write & execute the Homework directory. How is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

```
chmod 444 /Homework
```

Directories need the `x` permission in order to `cd` into them.

So make that

```
chmod 555 /Homework
```

(Personally I'd pick 755)

`root` overrides permissions in this scenario.

Comment: But why am I required to
Allow all users to read this directory. But nothing else.

??

Comment: I mean providing the execution seems to me that I didn't do the task correctly ?

Comment: `555` is `dr-xr-xr-x` which allows people to `ls` (the "r") and `cd` ("x") the directory.  They're both forms of "read".  There is no write access granted.